# Error 1 when trying to make file (mips, assembly)

Tags: linux, assembly, makefile, pipe

Im having a school project in assembly and have written a program which im trying to compile in mips. Its the third program I've done but this time when Im trying to make file i get this error message:

```
sde-as -march=r3k -O0 lab2.s -o test.o\
sde-ld -T linker_script test.o -o a.out\
test.o: In function 'While':\
: undefined reference to 'while'\
make: *** [Makefile:6: pipe] Error 1
```

The command that i write in the linux terminal is "make pipe"

Ive really tried to find a solution by googling, changing path etc. I've found some threads with people who've had similar problems but nothing has helped. Would really appreciate if someone knows what is wrong. Is something wrong with the code or is it something else?

Comment: Your program references the symbol `while` but never defines it.  The reference occurs in the function or after the symbol `While` -- note the case difference between the two.  Symbols are case-sensitive, so this might just be a typo?

Comment: Thank you, sir. It was just a typo as you suggested. It worked now and may feel like an idiot right now but at least I'm a glad idiot :)